# elisp regular expression build problem

Tags: regular-expressions

I have the following line :

```
mod_name func_name /users/username/workspace/path_name/file.c 283
```

I wanted to capture the 3rd and 4th entry in this line, I am able
to do that using regular expressions like so: 
`^(?:\S+\s){2}(\S+)\ ([0-9]+)`

How do I translate this into a lisp regex ? so that elisp functions can
understand. I couldn't use the above regex into re-builder within emacs. Says it is an invalid expression. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: [Different regex syntaxes compared](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y/119906#119906)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Emacs regexps do not use `\S` or `\s` for non-whitespace and whitepsace. See `(info "(elisp) Syntax of Regexps")` for details. You can evaluate that which will jump to the corresponding info page.

It's far easier and more readable to use the `rx` macro to create regexps in Emacs. Here is my translation to `rx` syntax of your example:

```
(rx line-start
    (= 2 (and (one-or-more any) " "))
    (group (one-or-more any))
    " "
    (group (one-or-more digit)))
```

And here is resulting regex string:

```
"^\\(?:.+ \\)\\{2\\}\\(.+\\) \\([0-9]+\\)"
```

Note that **`any`** which is expressed in regexps as **"."** does *not* match newlines in Emacs.

Comment: Thank you explaining rx macro.

Comment: @Drew Thanks for editing!

Comment: '`**any**` which is expressed in regexps as "." does not match newlines in Emacs.' - you can also write it as `not-newline` or `nonl` to make that clearer.

Comment: @npostavs Thanks, nice to know!